# mounting point in azure databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I would like to use a mount point on azure databricks with this code:

```
dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/dz/')
```

but i have this error

```
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
```

what should i do in this situation?

i have create a mounting point with this code

```
mountPoint = "/mnt/dz/"
if not any(mount.mountPoint == mountPoint for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts()):
  try:
    dbutils.fs.mount(
      source = "wasbs://{}@{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(blobContainerName, storageAccountName),
      mount_point = mountPoint,
      #extra_configs = {'fs.azure.account.key.' + storageAccountName + '.blob.core.windows.net': storageAccountAccessKey}
      extra_configs = {'fs.azure.sas.' + blobContainerName + '.' + storageAccountName + '.blob.core.windows.net': sasToken}
    )
    print("mount succeeded!")
  except Exception as e:
    print("mount exception", e)
```

the code have run well, but now

```
dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/dz/')
```

is not working

Comment: Use dbutils.fs.mounts() to check if this mount has been created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details

The above error you are facing because you do not have **list** permission for that particular container in sas token.

**while creating sas token in permissions select list option:**
[image]

**Output:**

[image]